# Fail to convert an RDD to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark

I am trying to convert an RDD to dataframe but it fails with an error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3
>   in stage 2.0 (TID 11, 10.139.64.5, executor 0)

This is my code:

```
items = [(1,12),(1,float('Nan')),(1,14),(1,10),(2,22),(2,20),(2,float('Nan')),(3,300),
         (3,float('Nan'))]

sc = spark.sparkContext
rdd = sc.parallelize(items)

itemsRdd = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(id=x[0], col1=int(x[1])))

df = itemsRdd.toDF() # The error is thrown in this line.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems with this code.

The first problem, which you have probably encountered here, is missing import of `Row` class, hence the method `toDF()` fails to execute and create a logical plan for you dataframe.

The second problem occurs in the definition of `col1` column. If you try to execute `int(float('nan'))` it will result in a `ValueError` and therefore crashes the execution later on when you call an action on the dataframe.

You can solve both problems for example this way:

```
items = [(1,12),(1,float('Nan')),(1,14),(1,10),(2,22),(2,20),(2,float('Nan')),
         (3,300),(3,float('Nan'))]

sc = spark.sparkContext
rdd = sc.parallelize(items)

df = rdd.toDF(["id", "col1"])
```

If you wish to retype the columns, I'd suggest to use the `cast` method on the specific column you want to retype. It's a bit safer, faster and more stable way to change column types in Spark dataframe rather than forcing a Python type on each row.